# How to solve IndexOutOfBoundsException in JBoss AS?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, jboss

I have a web application running for a few months now on JBoss AS 7.1.1 but from a few weeks now, strange exceptions has appeared non related to my App.

```
08:46:44,700 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (ajp--127.0.0.1-38009-173) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1562)
        at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1562)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
        at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1652)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367)
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:577)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:301)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at com.b2b.web.filter.CookieVisitaFilter.doFilter(CookieVisitaFilter.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at com.b2b.web.filter.DomainFilter.doFilter(DomainFilter.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:505)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems related to jBoss but i have no idea where to look

Comment: Can you put the code that you use for that? You have an `IndexOutBoundsException` so you are trying to access to a part of your code that doesn't exists (for example a position of an array that doesn't exists).

Comment: Hey, there is no références to my code in the stack trace, besides of com.b2b.* both of them are filters and no one uses à list

Comment: and this?  `at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)` in the third line.

Comment: Thanks Error404,

Seems like it's been called by Jboss Itself, not by me

Comment: Fixed or still having an issue?